# Forcing HttpUrlConnection to ipv4 only

Tags: android, ipv6

I'm doing the typical HttpUrlConnection download to fetch data into my app, but I'm discovering problems on certain networks.

These networks are assigning ipv6 addresses to the devices even though the networks don't work properly with ipv6. Of course, Android fails over from ipv6 to ipv4.

In Jellybean (4.2.2) the failover takes close to a minute, which is way too long for a mobile app. We have do not have direct control of these networks.

If I can force HttpUrlConnection to use only ipv4 everything will be fine, but I've found no way to do this. Has anyone else?

Comment: While you work on a solution, also make sure your customers are aware that it is their mobile carrier causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't force the application to use IPv4. We are deploying networks that have IPv6-only connectivity (with NAT64/DNS64) and IPv4-only applications will break on such networks. The world is running out of unused IPv4 addresses, and parts of the world (Asia, Europe, Middle East) are already out.

To solve this please look at [RFC 6555: Happy Eyeballs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6555). It describes an algorithm that will try IPv6 first but falls back to IPv4 so quickly that the user will hardly notice it (or usually won't notice it at all).

Unfortunately I don't know of a good Java implementation you could use on Android, but I hope others will be able to point you in the right direction. (or you can be the first to write an open source implementation and gain fortune and fame that way (well, fame at least ;))

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164175/using-ipv6-in-a-real-world-java-program

Comment: Michael: it does, which is why I explicitly mentioned that. Do you know of an example implementation in Java? My Java skills are too rusty :(

Comment: Nope, and Google doesn't have one either. From what I recall, Java just hides too much of the low-level stuff you'd need to implement this.

Comment: That is not good. It would mean that the only thing a developer can do is `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");`, and I doubt that that'll be allowed on Android...

Comment: It would help if mobile carriers would just do IPv6 properly instead of all this transition crap like 464xlat and such.